# Uploading To Apache server and limiting premissions to folders

Tags: c#, apache, upload

I am tryng to Upload to Apache server .
Now i would like to upload to onyl 1 folder where my other program will read it .
Here is my Directorys
UploadFolder
Data
Data2

I would like to make it so that other people cant acces data and data2 but acces Upload Folder .

```
webAddress = @"http://127.0.0.1:22868/BNt/";

        webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        WebRequest serverRequest = WebRequest.Create(webAddress);
        WebResponse serverResponse;
        serverResponse = serverRequest.GetResponse();
        serverResponse.Close();

        webClient.UploadFile(webAddress + name, "PUT",win+"ProgramData/HejaxDump/connect.txt" );
        webClient.Dispose();
```

Even if there is answer to it pleas link it Because i couldnt find it .

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: I used the Code in Post to Upload to Apache server                            Error messsage                                                                 https://i.gyazo.com/8a8d1d2f9eada41675e0ada355302d04.png

Comment: I dont know if i can bump thread or no but il try